# Unable to parse file from AWS Glue dynamic_frame to Pyspark Data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, aws-glue

Iam new to AWs glue.

I am facing issue in converting glue data frame to pyspark data frame :

Below is the crawler configuration i created for reading csv file
glue_cityMapDB="csvDb"
glue_cityMapTbl="csv table"

```
datasource2 = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = glue_cityMapDB, table_name = glue_cityMapTbl, transformation_ctx = "datasource2")

datasource2.show()

print("Show the data source2 city DF")
cityDF=datasource2.toDF()
cityDF.show()
```

### Output:

Here i am getting output from the glue dydf - #datasource2.show()
But after converting to the pyspark DF, iam getting following error

```
S3NativeFileSystem (S3NativeFileSystem.java:open(1208)) - Opening 's3://s3source/read/names.csv' for reading 2020-04-24 05:08:39,789 ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task
```

Appreciate if anybody can help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of a file are of UTF-8 encoded. You can check using file or convert using inconv or any other text editor like sublime.

You can also read the files as a dataframe using:

`df =  spark.read.csv('s3://s3source/read/names.csv')`

then convert to dynamic frames using fromDF()